# SearchView stretching RecyclerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm having an issue with my AlertDialog where i have a recyclerView and a searchView.

When i press on searchView it stretch the items from the recyclerView for a while and i would avoid that.

[image]

I think that the issue is that when i press on searchView as you can see on the screen it move the alertDialog a bit upper than it original posizion but i can't get how to fix it, here is my item RecyclerView xml and the xml with AlertDialog

recyclerView item xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Desc"
        style="@style/word_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/line"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PrePiu"
            style="@style/word_title"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PreMeno"
            style="@style/word_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp" />



    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

While here is the xml with AlertDialog

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:gravity="center"

    android:layout_margin="20dp"

    android:background="@color/colorWhite"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:padding="5dp">


    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/deskART"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

        android:text="VARIANTI"

        android:textColor="#008b58"

        android:textSize="20sp"

        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/TitleBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Descrizione"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/preMeno"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="+   -"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlSymmetry" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewVarianti"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/conBTN"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#008b58"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/convar"
            android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/piuBTN"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#008b58"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/piu"
            android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menoBTN"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#008b58"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/meno"
            android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/senzaBTN"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#008b58"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/senza"
            android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use same LinearLayout as id 'TitleBar' in your  custom RecyclerView layout ,
make sure the width height and weight of 'TextView' is same as in AlertDialog layout xml

Comment: still same issue also after changing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding the following code after creating the AlertDialog

```
Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow()).setSoftInputMode(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
```

Where dialog it's the AlertDialog object.